# Specifying a width and height of 100% generates JavaScript errors

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am attempting to render a Google bar chart. In my JavaScript, I have the following:

```
    var options = {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        chartArea: {
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            left: 85,
            top: 10,
            bottom: 60,
            right: 25
        },
        legend: { position: 'bottom', alignment: 'start' },
        annotations: { alwaysOutside: true},
        hAxis: {
            gridlines: { count: 10 },
        },
    };
```

When I execute this, I get the following JavaScript errors:

[image]

However, if I change the height from '100%' to '400' as shown below, the chart renders correctly with no JS errors.

```
    var options = {
        width: '100%',
        height: '400',
        chartArea: {
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            left: 85,
            top: 10,
            bottom: 60,
            right: 25
        },
        legend: { position: 'bottom', alignment: 'start' },
        annotations: { alwaysOutside: true},
        hAxis: {
            gridlines: { count: 10 },
        },
    };
```

If it matters, the div that represents the chart is in a Bootstrap container. The HTML looks as follows:

```
    <div id="chart_div" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    </div>
```

Comment: I've updated my question to show the HTML.

Comment: Thank you. I'm less concerned about this issue than the last one you helped with. I really don't want a height of 100% anyway but I would like to know why this is happening.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is here that google chart width and height expect a number, but you are sending a string including the % symbol, this is what the NaN error is, its Not a Number!

EDIT

Apologies, the documents state it can be either a number or string, my guess is that it is trying to convert it to a string and the % causes the error

chartArea.width 
Type: number or string
Default: auto

chartArea.height
Type: number or string
Default: auto

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#configuration-options

Edit 2

I was actually looking at the chartArea.height and not height.

The documentation states that the height and weight should be in pixels, so a number

height
Height of the chart, in pixels.

Type: number
Default: height of the containing element

width
Width of the chart, in pixels.

Type: number
Default: width of the containing element

So I cant really answer your original question, why the chart will accept a string is a mystery, when it is clearly defined as requiring a number.

Comment: If the '%' is the issue, why does it accept a width of '100%' when the height is set to '400' (without a '%')?